# mySQL exclusive records

Tags: mysql

I have many ClientIDs to many pageids

Eg.

ClientID 1 PageID 3 
ClientID 1 PageID 2 
ClientID 2 PageID 3 
ClientID 3 PageID 3

In a query I want to bring up the record with only PageID 3 exclusively.

So in my result i should get Client 2 and 3 and client 1 should be omitted out of the results... Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT clientid FROM
  clients
GROUP BY
  clientid
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = COUNT(IF(PageID = 3, PageID, NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID
FROM table
WHERE PageID = 3
AND ClientID NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM table WHERE PageID != 3 )
```

Or this ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ClientID
FROM table a
JOIN ( SELECT ClientID, COUNT(*) AS total FROM table GROUP BY ClientID ) b ON a.ClientID = b.ClientID
WHERE b.total = 1
AND a.PageID = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't work see comment below !**

```
SELECT ClientID FROM table WHERE PageID=3 GROUP BY ClientID HAVING count(ClientID)=1
```

This the idea, try something around.

Hope this help.

Comment: You are just restricting the possibility for duplicates within the same PageID instead of removing them if they are in other pages as well.